# gnuplot: strptime and milliseconds

Tags: gnuplot, strptime

I have some time data like this `15:46:47.234` and would like to interpret it with `strptime`. But when I tipe `strptime("%H:%M:%.3S",strcol(3))`, I always get this warning: `Bad time format in string`.

Does anybody know what's wrong?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't specify any digits for the `%S` format, simply use `"%H:%M:%S"` which also handles milliseconds correctly:

```
t = '15:46:47.23'
print strptime('%H:%M:%S', t)
```

This prints `56807.23` on the screen.